# How can I map through this data? Error says 'Cannot read property 'map' of undefined'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I keep on having this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

I'm using a useEffect to retrieve the data from firestore

```
 const [users, setUsers] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = firestore
      .collection("users")
      .doc(result)
      .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
        const arr = [];
        arr.push({
          ...snapshot.data(),
        });

        setUsers(arr);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
      });

    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };
  }, []);
```

JSON.strinify result of the data:

```
[
  {
    email: "hello@gmail.com",
    createdDate: { seconds: 1629266050, nanoseconds: 525000000 },
    displayName: null,
  },
];
```

this is inside my functional component of which I keep having the error saying cannot read property of map

```
  {users.map((user) => (
          <li>{user.email}</li>
        ))}
```

Comment: `const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);` set the intial state to `[]`

Comment: Missing valid initial state, `const [users, setUsers] = useState();` you should provide valid initial state that can be mapped during the initial render and subsequent renders until it is populated. Voting to close as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo". Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, check that users data is fetched and stored in the state

```
{users && users.map((user) => (
          <li>{user.email}</li>
        ))}
```

Answer (score 1):

The initial state is missing, so it takes it as undefined. Hence, it tries to map undefined.

Add initial state like this
 `const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);`

Answer (score 1):

At first initialize the state with empty array. Initially the state is null so the map is undefined

```
const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
```

Then  do a conditional checking like below for safety.

```
{
users?.map((user) => <li>{user.email}</li>)
}
```

This ? Checks if the value is undefined or not.

Reference - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Comment: Your code has the same flaw as what you point out in the other answers, just FYI.

Comment: No, if `users` is updated to some other non-null, defined value not an array, this code still fails. Take for example, `users` is updated to `{ foo: 'bar' }`. Stones and glass houses, if you want to point out gaps in other's code make sure your's doesn't have the same issue. Try `users?.map?.(user => ......` if you really want to guard accesses, this way both `users` ***and*** `users.map` must exist.